# How to bind anonymous function to form's onsubmit and then access that form's contents for AJAX submit?

Tags: javascript, forms

I can't figure out how to attach an anonymous function to a onsubmit event of a form. I want to bind anonymous AJAX JS logic to a feedback form. I don't want to rely on unique ids.

I was using

```
feedbackform.onsubmit = function (e) {
```

But that doesn't work well if I have several of the [same *feedbackform* forms](https://github.com/kaihendry/vanilla-php-feedback-form/blob/master/feedback/index.html) embedded.

A way forward might be to use `onsubmit="return feedback()"`, however I can't work out how to access the form's content from the [feedback function](https://github.com/kaihendry/vanilla-php-feedback-form/blob/master/feedback/feedback.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good idea to post our code here, not somewhere else that may or may not be available for as long as the post here is.

You are relying on a practice where IE made ID and NAME attribute values into properties of the global object that referenced the related elements. That was widely considered a "bad thing", but was copied by most other browsers in order to be compatible with IE (most sites at the time were written almost exclusively for IE, which had about 95% user share).

Then came open standards and a concerted effort to support them. Now no one with any sense uses it, though it's still supported.

Anyhow, the global *feedbackForm* will reference either a single form with the name *feedbackForm*, or a collection of elements with the name *feedbackForm* if there's more than one, much like you'd get if you did `document.getElementsByName('feedbackForm')`.

Unless of course you declare a function or global variable named *feedbackForm* (see why it was a bad idea?).

So you can either iterate over that collection to find the form you want, or as *One of One* suggests, you can pass a reference to the form from the submit listener:

```
<form onsubmit="return feedback(this)" ...>
```

and in the function:

```
function feedback(feedbackForm) {
```

so now the **local** variable *feedbackForm* references the form whose handler called the function.

Comment: Thanks https://github.com/kaihendry/vanilla-php-feedback-form/commit/10b05600736e7b043270847c4a43dec9c4ac85d0 Do please review / feedback the rest of this little project. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Inside your feedback function change `feedbackform.` to `this.`.

Comment: Explaination: "this" in JavaScript refers to the "owner" of the function. In this case, it will be the form.

Comment: But the OP is using in–line listeners, so *this* is the global/window object. @Ben—it references whatever it's set to in the call.

Comment: Didn't see that he didn't pass 'this' in. Good catch.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the contents simply by :

```
$('feedbackform').submit(function() {
  $(this).serialize();      
});
```

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag or mention of it in the post.